# How to use to converter in sping jpa

Tags: java, xml, spring, datetime, localdate

To run the application i use tomcat 8.5.50 package in war.
i use spring 5.2 version.
in my code i want to use LocalDataTime  like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="meals")
public class Meal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "date_time")
    @Convert(converter = MealConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime datetime;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "calories")
    private int calories;

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDatetime() {
        return datetime;
    }

    public void setDatetime(LocalDateTime datetime) {
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }

    public void setCalories(int calories) {
        this.calories = calories;
    }
}
```

my Converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MealConverter implements AttributeConverter<Meal, String> {

    private static final String SEPARATOR = ", ";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Meal meal) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(meal.getCalories()).append(SEPARATOR)
                .append(meal.getDatetime())
                .append(SEPARATOR)
                .append(meal.getDescription());
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Meal convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        String[] rgb = dbData.split(SEPARATOR);
        Meal meal = new Meal(Integer.valueOf(rgb[0]),
                LocalDateTime(valueOf(rgb[1]),
                rgb[2],
                rgb[3]);
        return meal;
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the converter in the convertToEntityAttribute method but the compiler does not allow me to do this. What needs to be fixed in my Converter?

[image]

Comment: Your converter can convert `String` column value to `Meal` object, but field type is `LocalDateTime`.  It looks weird using `MealConverter` inside `Meal` entity

Comment: could you throw off the link how to do it right?

Comment: https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/dealing-with-javas-localdatetime-in-jpa

Answer (score 0):

```
    Meal meal = new Meal(Integer.valueOf(rgb[0]),
            LocalDateTime(valueOf(rgb[1]),
            rgb[2],
            rgb[3]);
```

1. Your `Meal` class doesn’t seem to have any explicit constructor, so you cannot pass arguments to `new Meal()`. You seem to be trying to pass two arguments. You may want to create a suitable constructor, or you may want to pass the two values into the `Meal` using setters after the object has been created.
2. `LocalDateTime` is a class, but you seem to try to call it as a method with three arguments. If that’s `java.time.LocalDateTime`, you probably intended `LocalDateTime.of(someArguemts)`, but there isn’t any three-argument `of` method of that class. If you explain better what result you expect, we can guide you better.
3. As the first argument to `LocalDateTime` you have a call to a `valueOf` method that doesn’t seem to be declared in your class. You may have intended `Integer.valueOf` as in the preceding line.
4. If you are trying to use your RGB values for initializing a date (don’t know what sense that might make), be aware that if your RGB values go up to 255, this will likely fail with an exception since month numbers only go up to 12 and day of month up to 31.

I am far from sure that the following is correct or does what you want it to do, but it’s a guess at what you may be after.

```
@Override
public Meal convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    String[] fields = dbData.split(SEPARATOR);
    Meal meal = new Meal();
    meal.setCalories(Integer.parseInt(fields[0]));
    meal.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.parse(fields[1]));
    meal.setDescription(fields[2]);
    return meal;
}
```

I am trying to do the opposite of your `convertToDatabaseColumn` method. I have discarded the variable name `rgb` because I didn’t see how it couldn’t be misleading here.

Comment: i did like yo say, but such an error occurs: Field error in object 'mealsCreate' on field 'datetime'; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [mealsCreate.datetime,datetime]; arguments []; default message [datetime]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'datetime': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]

Comment: I don’t know where that comes from or why. Might it come from some other part of your code than the method I provided?

Comment: I think this is connected with this class.